# Django access local storage

Tags: reactjs, django

I am using jwt tokens for authentication, react for frontend and django for backend. I have two models `User` and `Post`. When a new post is made I want to associate it with the user who made it. I use axios to make a post where I send a request in a django serializer.

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        depth = 1
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(self.context['request'].auth)
        return Post.objects.create(user=self.context['request'].user)
```

The problem is that the current user is `AnonymousUser` even if the token exists. So I thought to access the authToken from localStorage and add it by the token. Should I store authTokens in cookies and access them by there or is there another way? Is it even good to store them in cookies.

Edit:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend']
}
```

Comment: Are you using a library like djangorestframework-simplejwt? Can you post your `REST_FRAMEWORK` variable in `settings.py`

Comment: I added the rest framework code.

Comment: store in local storage and pass it in API call as a Bearer Token.

Comment: So I am gonna send extra data in ``request``?

Comment: @zequuee1 yes in headers like this `headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}'}`
fetch token from local storage